# .htaccess one part of URL is user friendly other is query

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have folder structure like:

```
- templates
    - search.php
    - page.php
    - index.php
- index.php
```

It's not full structure, but its enough for this question. `Index.php` have task to include file based on first query named `page`. Then, through template class, I get the right template. `.htaccess` for this part looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Now comes the part that I can't solve. I have another query, with search string.

`index.php?page=search&q=some+query` is sample of non-friendly URL. Now, I want to make this URL to look like `http://www.domain.com/search?q=some+query`.

I tried with `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?q=([a-zA-Z0-9\+\%]+)$ index.php?page=$1&q=$2` but I get an `Undefined index: q in ...`.

Question is, how can i make first query to act like a static page and second to act like a query string from that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `QSA` flag in your first rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.
- You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule` directive.

Comment: This does the job, thanks a lot. Appending `[L,QSA]` at the end of the first rule worked.